# What should i do to automatically store my gps coordinates in mysql database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, gps

i have no errors in my codes, what i want to learn is the passing of data to my database without having a button. Currently i have to click my button first before i can pass my gps coordinates to my database, but as i have mentioned, i want to pass it at the time that my application is running.

This was my codes:

**

```
public class Sample extends Activity{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    EditText textLat;
    EditText textLong;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/SampleLocation/index.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        textLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
        textLong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
        Button btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        //to run the location class
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new myLocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

        //to run the createnewproduct class
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

    }
    class myLocationlistener  implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sample.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending Location");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String latitude = textLong.getText().toString();
            String longitude = textLat.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Echos.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }   
}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your DB already implemented (by extending SQLiteOpenHelper for example) then you could make calls to write to the database in the onLocationChanged() method of your listener.

Probably best to carefully control how often you write to the database using the parameters in the call to requestLocationUpdates on the locationManager. If you have a button that already writes to the DB then this should be simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason why i cannot do it is that im just new in android programming.

Comment: Please can you post the code where you write to the database when the button is clicked, as you said in the question?